# How to make a CGAffineTransform permanent?

Tags: iphone, ios, cgaffinetransform

According to this answer there's a way to make a CGAffineTransform permanent:

[iphone - making the CGAffineTransform permanent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703171/iphone-making-the-cgaffinetransform-permanent)

but it's not explained... the answer tells about a copy that is generated by the animation but isn't clear how to get it and assign to the original object, so this is the code, how to make it permanent?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

float angleRadians = 180 * ((float)M_PI / 180.0f);
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleRadians);

self.myView.transform = t;
[self.myView setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 220)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try going a level down to Core Animation and apply transform animation with following properties:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: t];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: t];
animation.duration = 0.0;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
[yourView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];
```

Then you can do other core animations and it should retain the transform. Don't forget to import QuartzCore framework.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing CATransform3D and not CGAffineTransform?

Comment: This works if you define t like this: CATransform3D t = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleRadians));

Although the key portion, in answer to the question is setting animation.removedOnCompletion to NO.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 4.0 or greater Apple recommends using Block based animations

reference: [What are block-based animation methods in iPhone OS 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126833/what-are-block-based-animation-methods-in-iphone-os-4-0)

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut 
                 animations:^{ self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI) } 
                 completion:NULL];
```

Not sure if this will solve your problem exactly, but it is a step in the right direction.

Comment: the animation block works, but when i pinch to zoom the view come back to original state

Comment: Was your pinch-to-zoom mechanism created by you?  If so, applying a new transformation (e.g. scaling to make it larger) would override the rotation if you used the method CGAffineTransformMakeScale as opposed to CGAffineTransformScale